# What handler should I use to run code when a new file is loaded?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am writing an addon that requires a function (`update_focal_length`) to be called each time the camera is moved. As a quick and easy way to solve this, I append this function to `bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post` and `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post`. This works very well.

However, after closing Blender and reopening it, I find that even though my addon registers, `update_focal_length` is not called upon scene change anymore. The code works great when I use the checkbox to manually un-register and re-register the addon.

In an attempt to solve this problem, I also tried appending `update_focal_length` to `bpy.app.handlers.load_post` and `bpy.app.handlers.load_pre`, but the behavior continues to be the same. Ideally, I would like this function to be called when a file is loaded, and continue to be called each time the scene changes after that.

Here is the relevant code:

```
def update_focal_length(self, context):
    # for each camera with focal_lock enabled...
    for camera in bpy.data.cameras:
        if camera.focal_lock.enable_lock and camera.focal_lock.focus_object != None:
            currentDistance = distance_to_plane(camera.focal_lock.focus_object)
            camera.lens = currentDistance * (camera.focal_lock.focal_distance_ratio)

#...#

handlers = [bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post, bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post, bpy.app.handlers.load_post, bpy.app.handlers.load_pre]
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Camera.focal_lock = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=FocalLockSettings)

    for handler in handlers:
        [handler.remove(h) for h in handler if h.__name__ == "update_focal_length"]
        handler.append(update_focal_length)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Camera.focal_lock


    for handler in handlers:
        [handler.remove(h) for h in handler if h.__name__ == "update_focal_length"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Any ideas on how I may achieve this effect without users having to un-register and re-register my addon each time? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: The handler aside, the add-on just adds a 'track to' constraint based on the the focus object and allows to bake the focal lenght, correct? Since the code is a bit of a mess and there is no documentation, do you mind adding a bit more details about what the add-on actually should do?

Comment: @brockmann Yeah, no problem! So the main feature is to have the ability to create the vertigo effect, as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=db8TEAO8qDM. It does this by setting the camera's focal length to the current distance the camera is from an object multiplied by a the ratio between the original distance and focal length.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html) says

> By default handlers are freed when loading new files, in some cases
> you may want the handler stay running across multiple files (when the
> handler is part of an add-on for example).
>
> For this the **bpy.app.handlers.persistent** decorator needs to be used.

and includes an example of the decorator.

[image: persistent decorator in use]

I believe this is what you are looking for; rather than trying to find a hook at load time.

Comment: Hey, this worked! Thank you so much!