# Add autorun script to rig

Tags: python, animation, scripting, rigging

So I've seen that some rigs like the Cloud rig that it has a script that autoruns every time the blend file is opened. Also, when the rig is linked, the script comes with it. And since I have a rig with a python addon, I want to add functionality just like that. But I don't know how to do so.

I see that the rig uses a custom property, but I didn't understand it.
[image]

It has this line on the value. What does this mean?
`<bpy_struct, Text("cloudrig.py") at 0x0000014375FF3408>`

Comment: It's a pointer property to a text block. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194681/rigify-automatically-link-ui-text-file-in-2-8  Set the text block to autorun https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36821/start-script-on-open-blender-file

Comment: If your scripts are in an Add-on, you can use the `@persistent` decoration described in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/237154/42221)