# Registering Persistent Scene Type Properties

Tags: python

I'm trying to register input variables by extending the scene type using the following line of code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty

bpy.types.Scene.myInt = IntProperty(name = "Int Name", default_value = 2)
```

Which works, but this gets removed every time I save and reload the blender file. How can I make it persistent?

Comment: You need to transform your script into an addon an register it as a regular addon

Comment: I did that, but it's still not registering permanently. myInt will have to be defined again on the next load.

Comment: Could you add your final code to the question so we can take a look and see how to make it work ?

Comment: Got it, thank you. I found this post:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235572/what-handler-should-i-use-to-run-code-when-a-new-file-is-loaded/237154#237154